# Sign in with apple and react

Tags: reactjs, apple-sign-in

I am struggling to fully wrap my head around the flow for Signin with apple - trying to implement it on a React frontend /PHP backend app.

What I find confusing here is that the redirect_uri directly makes a post call to an endpoint in my back end. From there, how do I process that data and then in turn regain control on the react side once it's complete?

Comment: I would suggest using the popup option. That way you can catch the response in the frontend and manually trigger a request to the backend. Note that the popup window wont work on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I know nothing about React, but I've just dealt a lot with Apple Sign In. From what I understand, the flow should do the following:

1. Front End => Apple (redirect users to login with Apple)
2. Apple takes user input, logs them in
3. Apple => your backend (sends a POST to your server, where you do stuff like verifying `id_token`, exchanging `authorization_code` for `refresh_token`, saving refresh token and e-mail address)
4. Your backend => Apple (I'm assuming you return a response to Apple)
5. Apple => Front End (Apple returns your response to your front end)

Answer (score 0):

The issue I've found with Apple is they're returning a POST request (if you add scope to your Apple request). If you're using an SPA (React) the server running React won't accept POST requests so if your callback URL is to your React frontend this will fail.

I think there are two ways to get around this:

1. Point the callback URL to a web hook on your server which will do a HTTP redirect to your React URL (and just include the auth_code and id_token in the query params)
2. Intercept the Apple POST request before it gets returned by setting the usePopup to true (this library is a good example: https://github.com/patelmayankce/react-apple-login#readme)